# Apply function or property to multiple methods of same class

Tags: python, oop, python-decorators

In the following example, the class `MyExample` read a list of filenames which have underscores in their file names.

```py
class MyExample(object):
    def __init__(self, location: str):
        self.location = location

    def get_file_names(self):
        # For simplicity, lets just return an example of the output
        return ["my_file_name_01.txt", "my_file_name_02.txt"]

    def get_file_name_number(self):
        # Idem as before. 
        return ["file_name_01.txt", "file_name_02.txt"]

    def get_file_size(self):
        # It does not return a list of strings so the desired 
        # property or function will not be applied here
        return [3800, 4000]
```

When the code is executed, the results are

```py
my_object = MyExample("./a/random/path")
print(my_object.get_file_names())
print(my_object.get_file_name_number())
print(my_object.get_file_size())

# The results:
['my_file_name_01.txt', 'my_file_name_02.txt']
['file_name_01.txt', 'file_name_02.txt']
[3800, 4000]
```

Now, I would like to find a way to **apply a function or property** (let's call it `to_dot`) that can replace the underscores for dots from the output of `get_file_names()` and `get_file_name_number`. 
The final code should have to return something like

```py
# Calling this function with .to_dots
my_object.get_file_names().to_dots
["my.file.name.01.txt", "my.file.name.02.txt"] # <-- The desired output

# Calling this function with .to_dots
my_object.get_file_name_number().to_dots
["file.name.01.txt", "file.name.02.txt"] # <-- The desired output

# Calling this function with .to_dots
my_object.get_file_name_number().to_dots
AttributeError #  # <-- The desired output ... or something similar
```

Is there a way to add the `to_dots` to the class `MyExample` in order to replace the underscores of some of the methods inside? 
I am not very familiar with decorators but I suspect there could be a trick to do that. So far I have unsuccessfully tried with `@property` but as far as I know, there are many types of decorators.... Or maybe it can be done without decorators and I am very lost.
Thank you.

Comment: Is your question how to write a function that replaces underscores with dots, or how to apply any function to all items in a list, or how to write a decorator to transform the return value of a method with any function?

Comment: @mkrieger1. I know that with `str.replace` I can change the `_`  for `.` and that with a comprehension list (or many other ways) I can apply the replace to all the items . My question is on how can I add a function to some of the methods inside the class. Thank you.

Comment: I would make `to_dots` a standalone function that accepts a list. Then its called like this:

`to_dots(my_object.get_file_names())`

This is more flexible because now you can use it on any list object you want. Not just ones returned by this class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not pass the required output format (dotted or not) as optional argument to those methods?

```
class MyExample(object):
    def __init__(self, location: str):
        self.location = location

    @staticmethod
    def map_list(lst, dotted=False):
        return [s.replace("_", ".") for s in lst] if dotted else lst

    def get_file_names(self, dotted=False):
        return self.map_list(["my_file_name_01.txt", "my_file_name_02.txt"], dotted)

    def get_file_name_number(self, dotted=False):
        return self.map_list(["file_name_01.txt", "file_name_02.txt"], dotted)

    def get_file_size(self):
        return [3800, 4000]

my_object = MyExample("./a/random/path")
print(my_object.get_file_names())  # Underscores untouched
print(my_object.get_file_name_number(dotted=True))  # Underscores replaced
print(my_object.get_file_size())
```

Comment: Thank you @trincot. I must admit this is the simplest solution and I definitively use it in the code. I like it because in this way I will avoid making more classes and do more imports, besides it only adds a couple of lines to the original code. However, as the original answer was how to apply a function to different methods to a class, I have to vote for a more related answer to the original question. But for other readers of this answer, I suggest to give more votes to this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
from collections import UserList

class MyList(UserList):
    @property
    def to_dots(self):
        return [s.replace("_", ".") for s in self.data]

class MyExample(object):
    def __init__(self, location: str):
        self.location = location

    def get_file_names(self):
        return MyList(["my_file_name_01.txt", "my_file_name_02.txt"])
```

Result for

```
my_object = MyExample("./a/random/path")
print(my_object.get_file_names())
print(my_object.get_file_names().to_dots)
```

is

```
['my_file_name_01.txt', 'my_file_name_02.txt']
['my.file.name.01.txt', 'my.file.name.02.txt']
```

Comment: Thank you @Timus. I have accepted this answer as correct because this is answer is more related to the original question of the post however, after thinking it twice and according to your comment about functions of a list, I will not use this approach in my code. I realized that it could be a better practice to avoid using classes such as MyList because it will not return a real list. Maybe it is a debatable point but I think a better practice (or more pythonic) would be to use the approach suggested by trincot, which does not imply the creation of more classes.

Comment: @eliasmaxil I agree, I probably wouldn't use this approach either - depends a bit on the broader context. I should have made that clear in the answer, which was only intended to show how you could achieve what you were asking for in more narrow sense (never a good way to answer). Anyway, interesting question!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a *class decorator* to apply a *function decorator* to the specified class methods.

```
from functools import wraps
import inspect


def dec_methods(decorator, *members):
    """Class decorator to apply specfied decorator to specified members of class."""

    def dec_the_class(cls):
        for name, m in inspect.getmembers(cls, inspect.isfunction):
            if name in members:
                setattr(cls, name, decorator(m))
        return cls
    return dec_the_class


def to_dots(func):
    """Function decorator to replace '_' with dots in list of strings returned."""

    @wraps(func)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        results = func(*args, **kwargs)
        results = [result.replace('_', '.') for result in results]
        return results
    return wrapped


@dec_methods(to_dots, 'get_file_names', 'get_file_name_number')
class MyExample(object):
    def __init__(self, location: str):
        self.location = location

    def get_file_names(self):
        # For simplicity, lets just return an example of the output
        return ["my_file_name_01.txt", "my_file_name_02.txt"]

    def get_file_name_number(self):
        # Idem as before.
        return ["file_name_01.txt", "file_name_02.txt"]

    def get_file_size(self):
        # It does not return a list of strings so the desired
        # property or function will not be applied here
        return [3800, 4000]


my_object = MyExample("./a/random/path")
print(my_object.get_file_names())        # -> ['my.file.name.01.txt', 'my.file.name.02.txt']
print(my_object.get_file_name_number())  # -> ['file.name.01.txt', 'file.name.02.txt']
print(my_object.get_file_size())         # -> [3800, 4000]
```

Comment: Thank you @martineau, this answer also works. I just gave a vote to another which required less code to achieve the same results.

Comment: It's shorter because it's doing something different. In my answer the methods of the class are decorated so they do what you want automatically — i.e. you don't need to manually call `to_dots()` on the results yourself as in the other answer. The other answer is also changing the type of value the methods returns (although it is a subclass of `list`).

Comment: Yes, you are correct, the code delivers a list and not a subclass of a list, which is useful to avoid mistakes in other parts of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Define your own decorator:

```
def to_dots(func):
    def inner():
        original_return = func()
        return [item.replace('_','.') for item in original_return ]
    return inner
```

And use it as :

```
@to_dots
def get_file_names(self):
```